# MVC Hangfire Error when sending emails

Tags: c#, hangfire

I'm trying to send an email using the following code:

```
var engines = new ViewEngineCollection();
var viewsPath = Path.GetFullPath(HostingEnvironment.MapPath(@"~/Views/Emails"));

var eng = new FileSystemRazorViewEngine(viewsPath);
engines.Add(eng);

foreach (var EmailEntry in EmailEntries)
{
    IEmailService service = new Postal.EmailService(engines);
    var email = new EmailTemplateModel
    {
        ViewName = "EmailTemplateModel",
        FromAddress = "donotreply@email.com",
        EmailAddress = EmailEntry,
        Subject = "Task Report",
        Date = Dates,
        Task = DatesAndTasks,
    };
    service.Send(email);
}
```

But when I look in hangfire, it shows the following error:

> Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException
>
> Activation error occurred while trying to get all instances of type IViewEngine
>       Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation error occurred while trying to get all instances of type IViewEngine ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>       Parameter name: httpContext

Comment: What is `EmailEntries`? Also: hangfire operates in the background and independently of your MVC application, hence no httpContext. I am curious though: why are you using a ViewEngine here? Are you sure you need this?

Comment: Email entries is a list of emails(strings), when I try using this without the ViewEngine I get the following error: The virtual path '/' maps to another application, which is not allowed.